# Component does not render based on state change in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Project is not rendering when mapStateToProps is updated and props is not accepting in project component and if using combinereducers it works but without combinereducers the project is not rendering

```
 reducer.js
```

This is my reducer where i have maintained state but it gets updated here but in project component its does rendering state is updated

```
   export const initialState={
    rows:[],
    projectformvalue:{
    projectname:"",
    companyname:"",
    description:"",
    estimationcost:"",
  },
  tabledisplay:false,
  open:true,
}
const reducer=(state=initialState,action)=>{
  const newState={...state};
  if(action.type==='CHANGE'){
     return {...state, projectformvalue:{...state.projectformvalue, [action.payload.name]:action.payload.value}}
  } 
   else if(action.type==='SAVE'){
     let temp = state.rows;
     console.log(state.projectformvalue);
     temp.push(state.projectformvalue);
     return {...state, "rows": temp}
      //newState.rows.push({ ...newState.projectformvalue});
   }
  return newState;
}
export default reducer;

  project.js 

         import React,{Component}from 'react';
         import Actions from './Actions';
         import {connect} from 'react-redux';
        class Project extends Component{



            render(){
               let {rows} = this.props.states;
               console.log(rows);
            return(
                <div className="employeeRegister">
                    <Actions/>
                <table>
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                       <th>Project Name</th>
                       <th>Company Name</th>
                       <th>Description Name</th>
                       <th>Estimation Cost</th>
                       <th>Actions</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                   {rows.map(tablerows=>{
                       return (
                        <tr key={Math.random()}>
                           <td>{tablerows.projectname}</td>
                           <td>{tablerows.companyname}</td>
                           <td>{tablerows.description}</td>
                           <td>{tablerows.estimationcost}</td>
                           <td>
                               <button onClick={()=>this.props.handleEdit()}>Edit</button>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       )
                    })} 
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               </div> 
            )
        }
        }
        const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
            console.log(state);
            return { states:state.rows }
            }
        export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Project);
```

Comment: Is the state updating correctly?

Comment: @HarishSoni yes state is updating

Comment: is the log working on the render?

Comment: no log is not rendering

Comment: Make sure your `states` contains an array named `rows` and use const instead of let in your render: `const { rows } = this.props.states;`

Comment: @Milore its not working when changed

Comment: If you define `const { states } = this.props;` and `console.log(states)`, does it print the correct object?

Comment: @Milore no its not logging the object

Comment: Share your redux related code please

Comment: Side note: **do not use random values as keys for React lists!**  That will cause React to throw away the previous version of those components, every time.

Comment: @IgorStecyura i have shared it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In those lines:

```
let temp = state.rows;
 console.log(state.projectformvalue);
 temp.push(state.projectformvalue);
```

You are accidentally mutating `state.rows` (mutating the state will prevent `react` to re render the component when it changes). You should make a shallow copy instead like this:

```
let temp = [...state.rows]; // This won't mutate the old state.rows
 console.log(state.projectformvalue);
 temp.push(state.projectformvalue);
```